# How to get rid of confusing configuring grub-pc GRUB install devices

Tags: grub2, updates, update-manager

I've deployed a number of Ubuntu machines with Clonezilla. After an update they ask the user to install grub on sda or sda1. I assume it has to do with the hard drive changing as this is a cloned machine. It doesn't matter which option is selected but I want to make this screen just not show up. It's unacceptably difficult for end users to understand and there is no default option, in effect it makes it so users are unable to update their computers without IT assistance. Does anyone know how to do such? I suppose I need to tell grub what hard drive to use (always sda!) but I don't know how to do this.

[image]

Comment: A screenshot of what you are talking about would have been nice.

Comment: Added image, clicking forward makes it ask to continue without installing grub. All options are fine and nothing breaks anything but most users freak out and don't know what to do when they see this.